# Pandas uses substantially more memory for storage than asked for

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory

I'm using numpy (1.13.1) and pandas (0.20.3) on Ubuntu 16.10 with python 2.7 or 3.5 (same issues on either).

I was investigating pandas memory handling (specifically when it copies or does not copy data) and came across a significant memory issue I don't understand. While I've seen (many) other questions people have regarding its memory performance, I haven't found any that directly addresses this issue.

Specifically, pandas allocates a **lot** more memory than I ask it to. I noticed some pretty odd behavior when just trying to allocate a DataFrame with a column of a specific size:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
GB = 1024**3
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['MyCol'] = np.ones(int(1*GB/8), dtype='float64')
```

When I execute this I see my python process actually allocates 6GB of memory, (12G if I ask for 2GB, 21GB if I ask for 3GB, and my computer breaks if I ask for 4GB :-/) as opposed to the 1GB that was expected. I thought at first maybe Python was doing some aggressive preallocation, however if I'm only constructing the numpy array itself I get exactly how much memory I ask for every time, whether it's 1GB, 10GB, 25GB, whatever.

Further, what's even more interesting is if I change the code slightly to this:

```
df['MyCol'] = np.ones(int(1*GB), dtype='uint8')
```

It allocates so much memory it crashes my system (running the numpy call alone correctly allocates 1GB of memory). (**Edit 2017/8/17**: Out of curiosity I tried this today with updated versions of pandas (0.20.3) and numpy (1.13.1), along with RAM upgraded to 64GB. And running this command is still broken, allocating *all 64(ish)GB of available RAM*.)

I could understand a doubling or even tripling of the memory asked for if pandas makes a copy and perhaps allocates another column to store indices, but I can't explain what it's actually doing. It isn't exactly clear from a cursory glance at the code either.

I've tried constructing the data frame in a few different ways, all with the same results. Given that others use this package successfully for large data analysis I have to presume I'm doing something horribly wrong, although from what I can tell given the documentation this should be correct.

Thoughts?

Some additional notes:

1. Even when the memory usage is large, pandas still (incorrectly) reports the expected data size when memory_usage() is called (i.e. if I allocate a 1GB array it reports 1GB, even if 6-10GB has actually been allocated).
2. In all cases the index has been tiny (as reported by memory_usage(), which may be inaccurate).
3. Deallocating the pandas DataFrame (df = None, gc.collect()) does not actually free all the memory. There must be a leak somewhere using this method.

Comment: Try this instead: `df = pd.DataFrame({'MyCol':np.ones(int(1*GB), dtype=np.uint8)})`

Comment: @MaxU While this does a better job, it's still not perfect. There's a large overhead (~100% the size of the object, a bit more) that gets allocated (I presume this is making a copy of the data then). That seems to have more plausible explanations than whatever's going on in my example, but it doesn't help if I need to throw more than 15GB in memory unfortunately. (Note: this happens even if the data is split over multiple channels, e.g. 3 5GB channels needs almost 30GB to allocate using this method, so if a data copies are being made none of them are being freed until the very end.)

Comment: How much space does `df.index` take up?  How does memory use change if you add another column, possibly the same `np.array`?

Comment: @hpaulj After it's constructed via MaxU's method the index takes up 72 bytes. The final DataFrame is the correct size (15GB) it just allocates a lot of overhead to get there. If I allocate 1GB of doubles using my method above, the size as reported via df.memory_usage() is again 72 bytes for the index and 1GB for the data, although in this case ~10GB was actually allocated by the process.

Answer (score 1):

So I make a 8000 byte array:

```
In [248]: x=np.ones(1000)

In [249]: df=pd.DataFrame({'MyCol': x}, dtype=float)
In [250]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 1 columns):
MyCol    1000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 15.6 KB
```

So that 8k for the data, and 8k for the index.

I add a column - usage increases by the size of `x`:

```
In [251]: df['col2']=x
In [252]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
MyCol    1000 non-null float64
col2     1000 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 23.4 KB

In [253]: x.nbytes
Out[253]: 8000
```

Comment: I updated my question with some notes. Pandas reports the expected memory utilization (e.g. if I create a 1GB array, it reports 1GB) even if much more (e.g. 6GB) was actually allocated. The fact that it also doesn't free all that allocated memory when the object is destroyed and the garbage collector is run leads me to believe there may be a memory leak in pandas.

Comment: So you are more concerned about the memory usage along the way, not the final usage.  I wonder what happens if you make the numpy array, and then make a copy plus a `np.arange()` of the same size (the index array).  In other words, try to create the same final numpy arrays, but without the `df` structure.

Comment: Both, but this is the "final" usage. The DataFrame may only be 1GB, but if the total memory allocated (that remains allocated, not that was used in the process of constructing the object) is 6 times larger, that's a real problem. Also, note in the case of initializing with uint8 allocating 1GB actually blows up my memory (32GB) and crashes. Those are all problems. As mentioned in the post constructing the numpy array itself poses no problems, only putting it into a dataframe.

Comment: I suspect pandas is making at least one, it not two, copies of the numpy array.  Plus the index array.  And there might one or more temporary arrays if it scans the input for uniformity or what ever else it needs to do for indexing and dtype decisions.